# About Create NODE using cpp

Tags: c++

Hi every body i have some question:

```
struct NODE{
TYPEDATA data;
NODE *link;
};

NODE* CreateNODE(TYPEDATA n){    //1
struct NODE *node = new NODE;    //2
if(node){
node->data=n;
node->link=NULL;
}
return node;
}
```

1.why i must have * after NODE for CreateNODE
2.why must use new NODE
thank you

Comment: Learn what pointers are and how to declare a pointer.

Comment: thank you for answer, but i think if you have time for that answer, you can really "help" me or you also ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using new, you dynamically allocate memory for a node. New returns a pointer to the allocated memory. You indicate that a variable is a pointer by using * . Since you want to return that new node, you need to return not a NODE, but a pointer to NODE, thus effectively the return type becomes NODE* . If you don't know how pointers or dynamic memory work, I suggest you look at these links:

[pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

[dynamic memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

Comment: you really help me. Thank you